# Could blockchain voting bring both secrecy and traceability to elections?

Tags: voting, voting-systems, electronic-voting

This was raised in a [comment in another thread](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/9119/how-do-i-know-that-my-vote-was-counted/9121#comment37162_9121) and a user:

> It's not impossible, especially not with the kind of technology we have today. When you cast a vote, you could be given a randomly generated GUID which can identify your vote, but cannot be reversed engineered to identify you, unless you tell someone else what your vote GUID ...

This seems absurd to me, its trivial to steal or brute force that.

Is it true that, "It is impossible to have a secret ballot AND traceability of the actual votes"?